# ASP.net Core MVC - DateTime Variable Doesn't Display Expected Value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a website where I need to set the **ApplicationStartDate** & **ApplicationEndDate**. When I perform this operation, **ApplicationStartDate** displays correctly but **ApplicationEndDate** displays the value of previous record which should not be the case.

Here is the **.cshtml** file :

```
@model Derawala.Models.ViewModels.ParentForApply
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Set Application Period";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1 class="text-success mt-3"><i class="fas fa-calendar-week"></i> Set Date Range For Scholarship Acceptance :</h1>
<hr class="mx-n3" />
@if (ViewBag.IsDurationSet)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Success!</strong> Application Acceptance Is Set From <b>@WC.AppStartDate.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy")</b> To <b>@WC.AppEndDate.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy")</b>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
}
@if (WC.AppStartDate == DateTime.MinValue || WC.AppEndDate == DateTime.MinValue)
{

    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h4 class="text-primary p-2"><i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i> Start Date :</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="date" asp-for="@Model.AppPeriod.AppStartDate" class="form-control form-control-lg" required />
            </div>
            <div class="text-primary col-md-2">
                <h4 class="p-2"><i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i> End Date :</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="date" asp-for="@Model.AppPeriod.AppEndDate" class="form-control form-control-lg" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="submit" style="font-weight:bolder;" class="btn btn-success w-100 text-white mt-1">Set Duration <i class="fas fa-calendar-check"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="reset" style="font-weight:bolder;" class="btn btn-warning w-100 mt-1">Reset Date <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <h3 class="text-primary"><u>Currently Set As</u> : </h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4 class="text-danger p-2"><i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i> <u>Start</u> <u>Date</u> :</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="p-2">@WC.AppStartDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4 class="text-danger p-2"> <i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i> <u>End</u> <u>Date</u> :</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="p-2">@WC.AppEndDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
        <form method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4 class="text-primary p-2"><i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i> Start Date :</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="date" asp-for="@Model.AppPeriod.AppStartDate" class="form-control form-control-lg" required />
                </div>
                <div class="text-primary col-md-2">
                    <h4 class="p-2"><i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i> End Date :</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="date" asp-for="@Model.AppPeriod.AppEndDate" class="form-control form-control-lg" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="submit" style="font-weight:bolder;" class="btn btn-success w-100 text-white mt-1">Set Duration <i class="fas fa-calendar-check"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="reset" style="font-weight:bolder;" class="btn btn-warning w-100 mt-1">Reset Date <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        }
```

[HttpGet] Controller Method :

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task <IActionResult> AppPeriod(bool IsSuccess=false)
        {
            ParentForApply ParentVM = new ParentForApply();
            int count = await _db.AppDuration.CountAsync();
            if (count == 0)
            {
                WC.AppStartDate = new DateTime();
                WC.AppEndDate = new DateTime();
            }
            else
            {
                WC.AppStartDate = await _db.AppDuration.MaxAsync(i => i.AppStartDate);
                WC.AppEndDate = await _db.AppDuration.MaxAsync(i => i.AppEndDate);
            }
            ViewBag.IsDurationSet = IsSuccess;
            return View();
        }
```

[HttpPost] Controller Method :

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AppPeriod(ParentForApply ParentVM)
        {
            int id = await _db.AppDuration.MaxAsync(i => i.Id);
            var data = await _db.AppDuration.FindAsync(id);
            _db.AppDuration.Remove(data);
            AppDurationPeriod app = new AppDurationPeriod()
            {
                AppStartDate = ParentVM.AppPeriod.AppStartDate,
                AppEndDate = ParentVM.AppPeriod.AppEndDate
            };
            WC.AppStartDate = app.AppStartDate;
            WC.AppEndDate = app.AppEndDate;

            await _db.AppDuration.AddAsync(app);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("AppPeriod",new { IsSuccess = true});
        }
```

I am deleting the last inserted record and inserting new record in the table to use as the latest dates.

[image: Database Column stores the correct values]

[image: Website displays the incorrect value of AppEndDate]

[image: When I debug the code, something phishy happens in this line of code where it changes the value of AppEndDate from original value of database to 30-06-2022]

It can be seen in the images that, database has stored the correct values but website doesn't show the same value.
In the second line of **else block** of the last image, something phishy happenes when I debug the code. Second line of that else block somehow changes the value of **AppEndDate** from the original value to **30-06-2022**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you load the page, the largest data is fetched from the database table by default, you can change the `HttpGet` method you use to get the data like this:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AppPeriod(bool IsSuccess = false)
        {
            
            ParentForApply ParentVM = new ParentForApply();
            int count = await _db.AppDuration.CountAsync();
            if (count == 0)
            {
                WC.AppStartDate = new DateTime();
                WC.AppEndDate = new DateTime();
            }
            else
            {
                int id = await _db.AppDuration.MaxAsync(i => i.Id);
                var data = await _db.AppDuration.FindAsync(id);
                WC.AppStartDate = data.AppStartDate;
                WC.AppEndDate = data.AppEndDate;
                //WC.AppStartDate = await _db.AppDuration.MaxAsync(i => i.AppStartDate);
                //WC.AppEndDate = await _db.AppDuration.MaxAsync(i => i.AppEndDate);
            }
            ViewBag.IsDurationSet = true;
            return View();
        }
```

Test Result:

[image]
[image]